# Facebook Login is not working on the device with parse.com SDK v1.1.12

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, parse-platform

I haven't any problems with FB login until now. After i updated to the newest SDK first i received an error in the FB app on the device with iOS 6 while login in. Now the when i tap facebook in the view i just get an error that something went wrong and the FB app doesn't open. I don't see any errors being reported. This is my code to login

```
if(![PFUser currentUser]){
    MyLoginViewController *logInController = [[MyLoginViewController alloc] init];
    logInController.delegate = self;
    logInController.signUpController.delegate = self;
    logInController.fields =  PFLogInFieldsFacebook|PFLogInFieldsDismissButton;
    logInController.facebookPermissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"user_about_me",@"status_update",@"user_birthday", nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:logInController animated:YES];
}
```

This problem might have to do with changes to fb sdk 3.1 and write permissions but i am not sure.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thank You!

Comment: Did you ever figure anything out?

Comment: Check out facebook permissions in the iPhone settings page.  I think my app was disabled there.  Try to logout from facebook on the phone and login again.  If that doesn't work let me know i'll post the code that i am using to authenticate.

Comment: Yeah, I figured this out last night shortly after I posted. The issue was that my application wasn't allowed to access the Facebook data in iOS 6. Thanks!

Comment: @Brandon I'd be hesitant to post an answer with my findings, which at this point are 1.5 years old, even if I could remember. For future users though, I believe the answer lies in going into Settings -> Facebook on your iOS device and ensuring your application has been granted permission to use the local users Facebook account.